# How to select defaultValue with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a ReactJS application. I have the Select component of react-select below which is loaded with information obtained from a database. From this information there is a default value that must be selected every time the page is loaded. So far so good. My application works with the following code

```
<Select
   name="planting_system_id"
   id="planting_system_id"
   options={plantingSystemsList}
   value={plantingSystemsList.find(e => e.label === planting_description)}
   placeholder="Select..."
   isDisabled={apiData ? false : true}
   onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInputSelected("planting_system_id", event)}
/>
```

However, with this code I cannot select any other option that is available in the Select list.

Searching a little more the Select component has a parameter called defaultValue, where from the list of objects that will be available in my select I pass the option that I want to be displayed. For example list [3]. However, as it is data that comes from the database, the position of an object's list will change and I need to obtain this position dynamically but I'm not able to do it that way

```
<Select
   name="planting_system_id"
   id="planting_system_id"
   options={plantingSystemsList}
   defaultValue={plantingSystemsList[this.getIndexOf(plantingSystemsList, planting_description)]}
   placeholder="Select..."
   isDisabled={apiData ? false : true}
   onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInputSelected("planting_system_id", event)}
/>
```

```
getIndexOf(list, description) {
   const obj = list.find(e => e.label === description)
   return list.indexOf(obj);
}
```

However, if I do it this way it works

```
<Select
   name="planting_system_id"
   id="planting_system_id"
   options={plantingSystemsList}
   defaultValue={plantingSystemsList[3]}
   placeholder="Select..."
   isDisabled={apiData ? false : true}
   onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInputSelected("planting_system_id", event)}
/>
```

Comment: `planting_description` and `planting_system_description` both value are same?

Comment: Editing error. Adjusted.